# C# наследования

Tags: c#, наследование

Есть клас родительский и дочерний клас Foo и FooInherited соответствено

```
class Foo
{
    public name { get; set;}
    public Foo()
    {
        name = "Это первый класс";
    }

    class FooInherited:Foo
    {
        public FooInherited()<br>{
        name = "Это второй класс";
    }

    public void JustTest()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Just for test");
    }
}
```

Дальше такая запись:

```
Foo myClass = new FooInherited();
```

Теперь поле name равно "Это второй класс", но при этом метод JustTest() , который присутсвует в дочернем класе не доступен. Почему при обращении к myClass.name мы получаем значение, которое присутсвует в дочернем класе, но не можем обратиться к методу дочернего класа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут дело в ссылке, которую вы объявили. Если перевести ваши действия простым языком:
1. Вы объявляете ссылку Foo myClass.
2. Теперь myClass знает, что он будет ссылаться на экземпляр класса Foo.
3. В эту ссылку вы назначаете новый экземпляр класса FooInherited. Т.к. это класс наследуется от Foo, а следовательно имеет все поля и методы из него никаких противоречий не возникает.

Другими словами, вы объявили, что ссылка будет направлена на экземпляр класса Foo. И обращаясь к ней вы можете вызвать только то, объявлено в классе Foo. Назначить же в эту ссылку вы можете либо сам экземпляр, либо любого его наследника.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо за быстрый ответ.)